# SQL Server Agent not running on my computer have SQL Server 2014 express

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting the following error while trying to run `SQL Server Agent` from `SQL Server Configuration Manager`:

[image: Sql error screen]

Comment: There is no Agent for SQL Server Express

Answer (score 3):

You cannot enable SQL Server Agent on any **Express** edition, since the Express editions **do NOT include** SQL Server Agent.....

See [Feature Comparison of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-supported-features-for-sql-server-2016) which shows:

[image]